# How to force Debian to use a newer version of OpenSSL?

Tags: debian, compiling, openssl, openssh, shared-library

Today I installed ,,empty'' (just minimal set of packages) Debian 8.1 on my VirtualBox. I wanted to play with compiling apps from sources.

I started with OpenSSL: compiled from sources OpenSSL 1.0.1p.

```
user@debian8:/$ /opt/openssl/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
user@debian8:/$ ldd /opt/openssl/bin/openssl
        linux-gate.so.1 (0xb76ed000)
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => /opt/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xb767c000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xb748a000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb747f000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb72d5000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76f0000)
```

Then OpenSSH. First problem I had was that `./configure` complained that the version of my OpenSSL headers (1.0.1p) doesn't match the version of OpenSSL libraries (1.0.1k). I found out, that `apt` installed just libs of OpenSSL 1.0.1k.
So I did:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib ./configure (..params...) --with-ssl-dir=/opt/openssl/lib
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib make
sudo make install
```

This worked.

But: (notice the version OpenSSL 1.0.1k and the path of `libcrypto.so`)

```
user@debian8:/opt/openssh/bin$ ./ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
user@debian8:/opt/openssh/bin$ ldd ssh
        linux-gate.so.1 (0xb770b000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2 (0xb761d000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xb7451000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb744b000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libutil.so.1 (0xb7447000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb742a000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1 (0xb7411000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb73e0000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7235000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb770e000)
```

And, again, adding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` helps:

```
user@debian8:/opt/openssh/bin$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib ./ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.0p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015
user@debian8:/opt/openssh/bin$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib ldd ssh
        linux-gate.so.1 (0xb776f000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libresolv.so.2 (0xb7681000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xb748f000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xb7489000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libutil.so.1 (0xb7485000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb7468000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1 (0xb744f000)
        libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libcrypt.so.1 (0xb741e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7273000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7772000)
```

I of course tested if `sshd` works: it listens on 22, I can connect with PuTTY.

And now come my questions:

1. Maybe I did something wrong?
2. How can I force using version 1.0.1p of OpenSSL by my OpenSSH without adding LD_LIBRARY_PATH (I tried with `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`, but without any effect: `ldconfig` sees `/opt/openssl/lib`, but it doesn't make `ssh` or `sshd` use 1.0.1p).
3. Why do `openssl` and `ldd openssl` use the correct path without any `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`ing?

Answer (score 2):

See `man ld.so` for the documentation of the dynamic linker. To give your own compiled OpenSSL priority, put it into `/usr/local/lib`. Adding a new search path in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` should also work, maybe you put it too late? Try

```
LD_DEBUG=libs /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --list /usr/bin/ssh
```

to gain insight.  For you self compiled binary, an RPATH setting may help it find its own library, check with

```
objdump -x /opt/openssl/bin/openssl | grep RPATH
```

(taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836330/is-there-a-way-to-inspect-the-current-rpath-on-linux).

Comment: +1 for `RPATH`: widened my knowledge